# Validation message is prematurely triggered

Tags: jquery, validation, checkbox

I have following code, and I want it so that if I unchecked the checkbox it will show the validation message.

**My code**

**jQuery**

```
if($('#TermsAndConditions').is(':checked')) 
{
} else {
    alert('Not checked);
}
```

**View**

```
<div class="editor-field">
    <%:Html.CheckBox("TermsAndConditions")%> <%: Html.ActionLink("I agree Terms and Conditions", "Terms", "Home")%>
</div>
```

However whenever I load the form, an alert message shows. Can you help me identify the issue?

Comment: because its not bind to any event. whenever the form/page loads, the alert will fire. you need to bind it an event like `submit`.

Comment: What do you expect your code to do without setting it inside onchange handler of checkbox?!

Comment: The [tag:jquery-validate] tag is for a specific plugin.  Please be more careful when tagging questions. Edited.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This occurs because of your placement of your script at the top of the page. Essentially your script is loaded before the `#TermsAndCondition` checkbox exists in scope so it fails your conditions and triggers the else, and it is not triggered by an event either (such as form submission, or update of checkbox status) which is probably undesired.

You should preform the action when an event is triggered, such as when the checkbox status is changed.

```
$("#TermsAndConditions").on("change", function(){
   if($(this).is(':checked')) 
   {
   } else {
       alert("Not checked");
   } 
});
```

Or when the form is submitted

```
$("#YourFormId").on("submit", function(e){
   if($("#TermsAndConditions").is(':checked')) 
   {
       // Form will submit
   } else {
       // Form will not submit
       alert("Not checked");
       e.preventDefault();
   } 
});
```

[See working demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/vsvj5/)

Comment: You could use `$(this)` inside onchange handler

Comment: @roasted True, I have updated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Where you put your jquery code? Are you sure it's running after page is fully loaded? You probably need to put it in `$(function(){ .. code .. });` like this:

```
$(function(){
    if($('#TermsAndConditions').is(':checked')) {

    }
    else {
       alert('Not checked);
    }
});
```

Or like @Duk said bind it to submit event.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#TermsAndConditions').on('change', function () {
    if (this.checked) {

    } else {
        alert('Not checked');

    }
});
```

Or any other handler you wish as form onsubmit e.g.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sNmym/)

Answer (score 0):

As there is no condition for Event it fires on during page load.use `change` event

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#TermsAndConditions').change(function(){
            if($(this).is(':checked')) {

            }
            else {
               alert('Not checked);
            }
        });
  });
```

Comment: As OP said, alert is already showing so this is obviously not the issue here

Comment: in this case, onchange event is better as some browser (older?) will fired click event before checkbox state as changed giving not expected result

Comment: @roasted you are right As click is not the event meant for checkbox..thanks again update ans